# 403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website with a single quote, which I am not able to browse, and few with the same character on same domain it's getting redirected and I am able opens the URL.

l'Union-Européenne-Dans-l'Europe/xxxxx.html when removed the single quotes from url I am able to browse.

Result when tried to browse: 403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID:

Note: checked on clodfront access logs I could find the log with error code 403, not much information other than URI results  /l%27Union-Europ%25C3%25A9enne-Dans-l%27Europe/xxxxx.html

Comment: Please provide more details, do you have a WAF. What is the origin? Can you access the origin?

Answer (score 24):

Check your CloudFront configuration. This will occur because of below reasons:

1. The request is initiated over HTTP, but the CloudFront distribution is configured to only allow HTTPS requests.
2. The requested alternate domain name (CNAME) isn't associated with the CloudFront distribution.

You can refer this link also to resolve your issue: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cloudfront-bad-request-error/

Comment: This is a good summary of why this happens, and probably infers the solution. But can you edit your answer to also summarize the steps suggested by the AWS documentation? While links are welcome, answers should remain relevant even if the page the link points to is removed or renamed at a later date—as frequently happens! By summarizing the steps, you help ensure your answer remains useful for future readers, while simultaneously saving readers today the need to click through to yet another page.

Comment: Reason #1 was the issue for me. Quick solution: add `https://` in front of the CloudFront domain

Comment: Back again... this time I forgot to update the CNAME. Thanks

Comment: @radihuq, can you please elaborate ? How are you adding https:// infront of cloudfront domain :) ?

Comment: I had not added an "alternate domain" to the cloudfront distribution in the control pannel. While doing it, I also needed to "request a certificate", and then attach that to the cloudfront distribution. "general" => "edit"

Answer (score 6):

Posting my solution here because this was an arduous, weekend-long issue for me, and the solution was not that obvious. As Mani Ezhumalai's answer mentioned, the issue was alternate CNAME records needed.

In my case, it was `www.example.com` vs `example.com`. CloudFront requires both domains to be covered in the alternative domain names list, which requires a single AWS ACM SSL cert to cover both, as well as the appropriate CNAME records configured in the DNS.

Answer (score 4):

WAF rules are blocking the request
You could navigate to AWS WAF > Web ACLs > yourWebACL and search for block under Sampled requests
Optionally navigate from cloudfront settings
ref this image
[image]

Then check in the *sample request* as given in the below pic
[image]

Read more about this modification at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-error-request-blocked/?nc1=h_ls

Please don't disable WAF as is, but either the rule, which prevents this URL from *count* instead of the default action (in your case the default action seems to be blocked).

- To modify the rule, navigate to AWS WAF > Web ACLs > rule > Edit rule
- and then toggle the control for specific rule under *rules*

Comment: What if there is no WAF?

Comment: Wow, this saved my life, thank you so much, disabling "SizeRestrictions_BODY" or increasing the size of "Body Size Limit" works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if you are have a CloudFront distribution that is backed by an S3 bucket and you make a request for a file that is larger than the maximum size of a file that can be delivered through Amazon CloudFront, which is 30GB as of 2023-09-26: [https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#:~:text=The%20maximum%20size%20of%20a,to%20all%20Amazon%20CloudFront%20distributions](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20size%20of%20a,to%20all%20Amazon%20CloudFront%20distributions)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an issue of removing the body in the GET request in postman.  See: [Cloud Front : The request could not be satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351920/cloud-front-the-request-could-not-be-satisfied)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. It was WAF / Firewall which rejected the request. Try to disable that to verify.