# CloudFront distribution returns Error 400

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution set up with some Origins and associated Behaviours.  This is virtually a duplicate of another similar (working) distribution I have.  I get the following error when attempting to access the service through the alternative domain name:

```
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

According to other posts on this and other forums this is likely due to one of the following two issues (see [403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216585/403-error-the-request-could-not-be-satisfied)):

1. The request is initiated over HTTP, but the CloudFront distribution is configured to only allow HTTPS requests.
2. The requested alternate domain name (CNAME) isn't associated with the CloudFront distribution.

In case all CloudFront origins are configured for http and this is reflected in the actual call made to the service:

[image]

The CNAME has also been updated as can be seen here:

[image]

Testing the CNAME record with Route53 produces no error:

[image]

I am not sure where else to look for the issue.  I cannot find any differences when comparing to the working distributions I already have running.

[Edit]

Actually it is only a 400 error.  Not 403.

Comment: Is this a single page app or a progressive web app? Or is this a CDN? Is this only in HTTP or does HTTPS work as well. It looks like you are jut using the default URL for CloudFront so there is no domain set for this distro. Is that correct? If you are using a custom domain for this, can you show the config for the distro? It looks to me that you are trying to set a domain for the distro but you never set the domain for the distro. Need more details. Also, cloudfront is typically set as an A record using Alias.

Comment: So this is a difficult issue to discuss on SO since there are so many configs that must be set and that can be wrong.  This instances fronts a number of services through which are set up as the origins, the endpoints obviously being the behaviours.  On the service side we are only using HTTP.  There is a domain set and it is registered as a CNAME entry in Route53.  I can successfully ping the domain.  What specific additional details would be useful?

Comment: I have changed the domain to an A record instead of a CNAMEA but getting the same 400 error.

Answer (score 1):

if use Django, you can modify configuration ALLOWED_HOSTS, add the request address to ALLOWED_HOSTS of setting.py

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about Django.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was not a CloudFront issue.  It was incorrect configuration on the Django server that the endpoint was pointing to.  Will remove this question shortly.

Comment: Whenever you're ready  :)